# Notation for repeated composition of functions

Tags: notation, function-and-relation-composition

I have a repeated composition of functions ${T_n}(z) = {\tau _0} \circ {\tau _1} \circ {\tau _2} \circ  \cdots  \circ {\tau _n}(z)$

By analogy with $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {} ,\prod\limits_{i = 1}^n {} ,\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^n {} ,\bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^n {} ,$
I want to write ${T_n}(z) = \left( {\mathop  \circ \limits_{i = 0}^n {\tau _i}} \right)(z)$ or even ${T_n}(z) = {\mathop  \circ \limits_{i = 0}^n {\tau _i}} (z)$. Can I do this?

Comment: Maybe an unnecessary comment, but be careful with the definition of your series of compositions. The ordinary finite products and sums on the reals are commutative, so a notation like $\sum^n_j a_j$ is unambiguous, but a notation like $\circ^n_j f_j$ may be interpreted by some people as $f_0 \circ f_1 \circ f_2 \ldots$ and by others as $f_n \circ f_{n-1} \circ f_{n-2} \ldots$

Answer (score 5):

Let $f_n(x)$ be a sequence of functions indexed by $n$.

Define a new sequence of functions $F_k(x)$ indexed by $k$:

$$
F_k(x) = 
\begin{cases}
f_0(x) &: k=0\\
(f_k\circ F_{k-1})(x)&: k\gt 0
\end{cases}
$$

So you have, for example
$$
\begin{align}
F_0(x) &= f_0(x)\\
F_1(x) &= (f_1 \circ f_0)(x)\\
F_2(x) &= (f_2 \circ F_1)(x) = (f_2 \circ f_1 \circ f_0)(x)\\
&\,\,\,\vdots\\
F_{n}(x) &= (f_n\circ f_{n-1} \circ \cdots \circ f_0)(x)\\
\end{align}
$$

Then for your composition $f_n\circ f_{n-1} \circ \cdots \circ f_0$ of $n$ terms you can simply write $F_n$.

Of course you can define a new sequence $G_n$ for the ascending direction, i.e., $G_2 = f_0 \circ f_1 \circ f_2$.

Answer (score 4):

Basically you can do anything. Notice, however, that the classical operators $\sum$ and $\prod$ do not coincide with the symbols they represent. And old books used to have $\sum$ instead of $\bigcup$ and $\prod$ instead of $\bigcap$.

I personally understand the notation $\mathop{\circ}_{n=1}^N$, but it doesn't look appealing. By analogy, why don't you define $$\mathop{\rm C}\limits_{n=1}^N $$ or $$\mathop{\rm K}\limits_{n=1}^N ?$$
Anyway, I don't like them either...

Comment: I can't use K as that's already in use for continued fractions, because K = _Kettenbruch_, the German for Continued Fraction.

Answer (score 4):

Iterated **s**ummation and **p**roduct are represented by the Greek uppercase letters **s**igma and **p**i. As we can see, there is a clear phoneticity here.

The only phonetic Greek equivalent of 'c' in '**c**omposition' is kappa.

But as uppercase kappa resembles 'K', and is already used for continued fractions in some texts, we might use the lowercase kappa '$\kappa$' for our purpose:

$$\underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\Huge{\kappa}}} f_i \left( x \right) \equiv f_n \left( f_{n-1} \left( \dots f_2 \left( f_1 \left( x \right) \right) \dots \right) \right)$$

Let's see an example where we can use this notation. Suppose we were to find the derivative of the composition of $n$ functions w.r.t. the variable they act on, say $x$ :

$\frac{d}{dx} f_n \left( f_{n-1} \left( \dots f_2 \left( f_1 \left( x \right) \right) \dots \right) \right)$

The derivative as computed using the chain rule recursively turns out to be,

$f_n^\prime \left( f_{n-1} \left( f_{n-2} \left( \dots f_2 \left( f_1 \left( x \right) \right) \dots \right) \right) \right) \cdot f_{n-1}^\prime \left( f_{n-2} \left( f_{n-3} \left( \dots f_2 \left( f_1 \left( x \right) \right) \dots \right) \right) \right) \dotsm f_2^\prime \left( f_1 \left( x \right) \right) \cdot f_1^\prime \left( x \right)$

But using the notations for iterative product and composition using $\prod$ and $\huge{\kappa}$ respectively, the expressions become much more compact:

$$\displaystyle{ \frac{d}{dx} \: \underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\Huge{\kappa}}} f_i \left( x \right) = \prod_{i=1}^n f_i^\prime \left( \underset{j=1}{\overset{i-1}{\Huge{\kappa}}} f_j \left( x \right) \right) }$$

Answer (score 3):

If I were writing something in which I had to do a large number of these, the following is probably not quite what I would do:
$$
\overset{n}{\underset{k=0}\bigcirc}\ f_k \quad \text{ or } \quad \overset{0}{\underset{k=n}\bigcirc} f_k \ .
$$
Instead, I'd go over to [tex.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com) and ask how to make this thing look respectable instead of like a workaround.  I'd probably want it to be comparable in size and boldness to something like $\displaystyle\bigcap$ in $\displaystyle\bigcap_{k=0}^n A_k$ or to $\displaystyle\bigoplus$.  Before the `\begin{document}` I'd put `\newcommand{\Circ}{blah blah blah}` (with a capital "C" distinguishing it from `\circ`.

Answer (score 0):

Some years back Shota Kojima introduced notations for compositions in both directions. These may be found in the Wikipedia page, *Infinite Compositions of Analytic Functions*.