# Which symbol to use for composition of a sequence of functions

Tags: notation, function-and-relation-composition

I know how to write the composition of two functions: $f\circ g$ but I don't know whether there's a standard symbol for a sequence (similar to $\sum_i{f_i}$, $\prod_i{f_i}$ or $\bigotimes_i{f_i}$, etc.).

How would you write it?

edit: Would you understand $\bigcirc_i{f_i}$ without explanation?

Comment: Probably better is: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926247/notation-for-repeated-composition-of-functions

Comment: But I'd like to add that if you insert a one-sentence explanation of your notation, it won't matter if anyone can understand it without explanation.

Comment: Many thanks, sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: No apology is necessary, everything went the way it is supposed to go.