# Is there a notation that is after pi product?

Tags: summation, notation, exponentiation, products

I have been wondering that if there is a notation that works with powers.
What I mean is:

How there is addition (+) and after it; is multiplication (x) and after it; is exponentiation (^) and after it; is tetration (^^) and goes so on...

And then there is summation ($\sum$) and after it; is product ($\prod$) and after it; ??? (is there something after it?)

So, summation works like that:

$\sum_{k=1}^{4}{k^2} = 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 = 1+4+9+16 = 30$,

And, product works like that:

$\prod_{i=2}^{4}{i^i} = 2^2 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 4^4 = 4 \cdot 9 \cdot 256 = 9216$,

Then, is there something that works with exponents? Like it would work with something like that:

(assume A is the notation in this case) $A_{n=2}^{4}{n} = 2^{3^4} = 2^{81} =$ (too lazy to calculate it, put it in your calculator if you want)

Thanks for answers.

Comment: I surmise that the notation evolves because it is frequently needed to shorten math syntax in problems.  Your notion of $A_{n=2}^{4}{n} = 2^{3^4} = 2^{81}$ doesn't seem to arise often enough to have its own syntax evolve.

Comment: @user2661923 so are there chances for such a thing in maths to not exist yet?

Comment: 600 years ago, the equation $e^{i\pi} = -1$ would have been regarded as gibberish.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such notation, but be warned that it is likely to be more confusing than $\sum$ and $\prod$, because $+$ and $\times$ are associative but $(x, y) \mapsto x^y$ is not. So it suddenly matters a great deal what order the operation is taken in. (This is not a hard "no" for the idea, because we also can't freely reorder in a $\sum$ in real analysis.)

Comment: Have you thought about Knuth's uparrows? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation

Comment: @ancientmathematician that are operations related to the previous operations, such as multiplication related addition, exponentiation related to multiplication, tetration related to exponentiation, pentation related to tetration, hexation related to pentation, and goes infinitely so on

Comment: I think Knuth has answered your question. Full stop.

Comment: @ancientmathematician at which paragraph is it answered (if you talk about answer being in wikipedia)

Comment: At the very start it sets out how it extends addition, multiplication, exponentiation. Isn't that what you want to do?

Comment: I would use an uppercase $T$, for "tower".

Comment: $$2^{81}=2\cdots2\cdots2$$ (too lazy to write all digits).

Comment: @ancientmathematician yes, but it repeats only 1 number, like $^{n} 2 = 2^{2^{2^{...}}}$, what I want is; a power being repeated but being in order that is given, like not $2^{2^{2^{...}}}$, but like $1^{2^{3^{...}}}$ or ${(1+1)}^{{(2+1)}^{{(3+1)}^{...}}}$ etc, like exponent is repeat multiplication, and product is multiplication with an order/sequence (idk if sequence would be correct word for it)

Comment: @YvesDaoust wow thats unique tho, i like it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special case where the concerned operation is applied to the same variable multiple times is often represented using [Knuth's up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation):

$x \uparrow y = x \cdot x \dots \text{(y times)} \dots x \cdot x = x^y \\ x \uparrow \uparrow y = x \uparrow ^2 y = x^{x^{ \text{(y times)}^{x^x}}}$

And so forth. Such repeated operations, originating from the basic operator addition, are known as [hyperoperations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation) and are conventionally represented by the letter $H$ :

$H_1 \left( x, y \right) = x+y \\ H_2 \left( x, y \right) = xy \\ H_3 \left( x, y \right) = x \uparrow y = x^y \\ H_4 \left( x, y \right) = x \uparrow^2 y \\ \vdots \\ H_n \left( x, y \right) = x \uparrow^{n-2} y \\ $

Note that for more than two variables, a repeated hyperoperation $H_n$ is *no* longer commutative after $n=2$, and we must consider [right-associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity),

$x^{y^z} \equiv x^{\left( y^z \right)} \neq \left( x^y \right) ^z$

Keeping this in mind, one may devise a *general* notation for the repeated hyperoperation $H_{n}$ in the following manner. Let us start with three variables $x,y,z$,

$H_1 \left( x,y,z \right) = x + \left( y + z \right) = H_1 \left( x, H_1 \left( y, z \right) \right) \\ H_2 \left( x,y,z \right) = x \left( yz \right) = H_2 \left( x, H_2 \left( y, z \right) \right) \\ H_3 \left( x,y,z \right) = x ^ \left( y^z \right) = H_3 \left( x, H_3 \left( y, z \right) \right) \\ \vdots$

Moving on to four variables $x,y,z,t$,

$H_1 \left( x,y,z,t \right) = x + \left( y + \left( z+t \right) \right) = H_1 \left( x, H_1 \left( y, H_1 \left( z,t \right) \right) \right) \\ H_2 \left( x,y,z,t \right) = x \left( y \left( zt \right) \right) = H_2 \left( x, H_2 \left( y, H_2 \left( z,t \right) \right) \right) \\ H_3 \left( x,y,z,t \right) = x ^ \left( y^ {\left( z^t \right)} \right) = H_3 \left( x, H_3 \left( y, H_3 \left( z,t \right) \right) \right) \\ \vdots$

Therefore, for a general number of arguments $n$,

$$H_k \left( x_1, x_2, \dots , x_n \right) = H_k \left( x_1, H_k \left( x_2, x_3, \dots , x_n \right) \right) = H_k \left( x_1, H_k \left( x_2, H_k \left( x_3, x_4, \dots , x_n \right) \right) \right) = \dots$$

Or,

$$\boxed{H_k \left( x_1, x_2, \dots , x_n \right) = H_k \left( x_1, H_k \left( x_2, \dots \left( x_{n-2}, H_k \left( x_{n-1} , x_n \right) \right) \right) \right)}$$

Using the iterative [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) notation that I have described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4001934/879669), the same equation becomes more structured,

$$\boxed{H_k \left( x_1, x_2, \dots , x_n \right) = \underset{i=1}{\overset{n-2}{\Huge{\kappa}}} \: H_k \left( x_{n-i-1}, H_k \left( x_{n-1}, x_{n} \right) \right)}$$

From this, we learn that $\prod$ is just $H_2$ in the infinite-membered family of hyperoperations.

Comment: Thank you! That was what i was searching for.

Comment: Nice, I like the thought-out choice of symbol and completed expression