# Convergence of $\sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n\cdot \log(n)\cdot \log(\log(n))\cdot ...}$ with a twist

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Denote $\log^{\circ j}$ to be $\log$ composed with itself $j$ times, i.e. $$\log^{\circ 0}(n) = n,\ \ \log^{\circ 1}(n) = \log(n),\ \ \log^{\circ 2}(n) = \log(\log(n))$$
and so on.

As stated in Julien Clancy's answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574503/infinite-series-sum-n-2-infty-frac1n-log-n), the following series diverges for every $k$:
$$\sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\prod_{j=0}^{k}\log^{\circ j}(n)} = \infty$$

and the following series converges for every $k$:
$$\sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\log^{\circ k}(n)\prod_{j=0}^{k}\log^{\circ j}(n)} < \infty$$

For example, when $k=2$ we have:
$$\sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n\cdot \log(n)\cdot \log(\log(n))} = \infty$$
but
$$\sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n\cdot \log(n)\cdot \log(\log(n))^2} < \infty$$

Intuitively, by increasing $k$ the first series becomes very close to converging, but it still diverges for all $k$.

This naturally raises the question - Is the (first) series still diverging when $k$ is increasing with $i$? More rigorously, is the following series diverges:
$$\sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\prod_{j=0}^{i}\log^{\circ j}(n)}$$

The usual condensation test approach seems hopeless here. Maybe comparing the series to an integral could work. I don't even have any intuition whether this should diverge or converge!

Comment: You can also denote $F_j$ as $\log^{\circ j}$ (`\log^{\circ j}`). By $\log$, do you mean $\ln$?

Comment: Yes, By $log$ I mean $ln$. And for the notation of $F_j$, I followed the first answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926247/notation-for-repeated-composition-of-functions

Comment: We can compare the series to an integral $\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{\prod_{j=0}^{i}F_j(x)} dx$. If the integral converges, then the series must also converge, but $F_j(n)$ has a very slow growth, so it's not clear...

Comment: You might get inspired by this post? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1764465/1104384

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty},$ rather than $\sum_{i=2}^\infty?$

Comment: @BrunoB Well, that's a bit awkward - I completely missed the fact that when $n < \left\lceil \mathrm{e}^k \right\rceil$, my summands are not necessarily even positive! I think this question should be closed, as the linked question makes much more sense, and is also answered :)

Comment: I voted to close the question. While the linked question is not exactly the same as mine, after realizing the inconsistencies of my question I would probably want to edit it to be very similar to the linked question so...

Answer (score -2):

It is well known (and easily to prove) that for positive $a_n$ and decreasing the series $\sum a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum 2^n a_{2^n}$ converges. This result has a name, something like "condensation theorem" or something. Once you know this, just use it as many times as needed.

Comment: Hmm the problem with this argument, which looks fine in theory, is that you cannot really apply that test (Cauchy condensation test is the name) an "infinite number of times"? Or I guess you'd have to take the limit in the process?